# Can you combine the WSDL and XSD data from a WCF service?

Tags: wcf, wsdl, wcf-client

Is it possible to create a single file to generate a client from a WCF generated WSDL file (and any additional XSD files that are also generated from this service)

I can generate a valid client using svcutil.exe passing both the wsdl file and each xsd file, but I have a customer who is using a PHP tool to generate this and I wanted to see if I could make it easy for them by having only one file instead of many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can - with some clever WCF extensions. Check out these ready-made solutions:

- [Flatten your WSDL with this Custom ServiceHost for WCF](http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/09/23/flatten-your-wsdl-with-this-custom-servicehost-for-wcf.aspx)
- [Improving WCF Interoperability: Flattening your WSDL](http://blogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/archive/2007/05/10/414840.aspx)
- [Flatten WCF WSDL on demand](http://www.steverb.com/post/2008/11/22/Flatten-WCF-WSDL-on-Demand.aspx)
- [Inline XSD in WSDL for WCF](http://winterdom.com/2006/10/inlinexsdinwsdlwithwcf)

Hope that helps!

Marc

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.

The WSDL *types* element can contain multiple schema elements (each with its own namespace),
this means that *types* element from an imported WSDL/XSD can be put in the root document's *types* element under a schema element that represents the same namespace.
Other WSDL elements (*message*, *portType*, *binding* & *service*) use the root *definitions* element namespace, so these imported elements from different namespaces cannot remain under different namespaces when put in the same document.

Note however that only the *types* namespaces are used for the construction of SOAP messages, so changing
the namespace of these other elements (if necessary) will not affect the generated SOAP messages.