# XSD to Java Classes - Parsing Schema Problem

Tags: java, spring-boot, binding, xsd

When i want to generate java classes from xsd files is there a problem like,

```
parsing a schema...
```

[ERROR] Property "Title" is already defined. Use <jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.
  line 104 of http://www.xbrl.org/2003/xl-2003-12-31.xsd

[ERROR] The following location is relevant to the above error
  line 110 of http://www.xbrl.org/2003/xl-2003-12-31.xsd

[ERROR] Property "Title" is already defined. Use <jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.
  line 145 of http://www.xbrl.org/2003/xl-2003-12-31.xsd

[ERROR] The following location is relevant to the above error
  line 151 of http://www.xbrl.org/2003/xl-2003-12-31.xsd

Failed to parse a schema.

Here is ref link
http://www.xbrl.org/2003/xl-2003-12-31.xsd

thank you for any help

Comment: Have you tried to resolve the name conflicts? i.e save the xsd to your local machine and edit it to resolve the name conflicts.

Comment: No. Because this xsd belong to an integrator company where  i have to build an rest api. So i don't want to any change on xsd files.

Comment: The problem is coming from the [imported xsd](https://www.xbrl.org/2003/xlink-2003-12-31.xsd). You can try to download them both and [merge them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066951/need-a-tool-to-merge-an-xsd-schema-with-imports-and-includes-into-a-single-file).